# Manually controlling window or canvas rendering?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, rendering

**Situation**

I have an application which calculates the constant changing position of a number of elements (usually between 10 and 20 simultaneously). The calculations are done on a dedicated thread, which then fires an event to indicate the calculations are completed. This dedicated thread is running at a stable 100 frames per second.

**Visualization**

The visualization of the elements is done using WPF. I implemented a single canvas and have written custom code to add a visual representation of each element to the canvas. Positioning is performed using *Canvas.SetLeft* and *Canvas.SetTop*. This code is running inside an event handler on the dedicated thread, and thus does not affect performance.

**Problem**

Due to the fact that the elements are constantly moving, the movement appears to be *stuttering*. The only assumption I can make, at this time, is the fact that WPF renders at its own convience and attempts to reach a maximum of 60 frames per second. If you have additional comments about why this could happen, please, do enlighten me.

**Question**

How can I tell WPF to render when the dedicated thread has invoked the completed calculations? If at all possible, I would like to prevent rendering of the window/canvas until the calculations are completed, at which point the frame should advance and render the new information.

**Comment**

A lot of people do not like attempts to go beyond the default 60 frames per second, and neither do I. However, it is absolutely mandatory to be able to influence *when* the rendering occurs, prior to going down to 60 frames per second. This is to ensure that 60 frames per seconds does not influence the stuttering problem.

**Rendering (Code)**

This is the involved code for the actual layout update, as per request of Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson. The MainViewModel contains an ObservableCollection with ActorViewModel instances, created by the dedicated worker thread. These are then translated into ActorView instances to visualize the calculated data. Upon adding and removing instances, I intentionally used *Invoke*, rather *BeginInvoke* to ensure these routines are *not* the cause of a performance issue.

Upon completion of the dedicated worker computation, UpdateLayout is invoked in MainViewModel, at which point *UpdateSynchronizationCollectionLayout* is invoked to update the visualization. At this point, scaling and opacity are not utilized, and the same stuttering behaviour is observed when the instance Viewbox is omitted. Unless I'm missing something, the issue should be related to the fact that I cannot check nor control the rendering time or speed.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the added ActorViewModel instances and the created ActorView wrapped in a ViewBox.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<ActorViewModel, KeyValuePair<Viewbox, ActorView>> _hSynchronizationCollection = new Dictionary<ActorViewModel, KeyValuePair<Viewbox, ActorView>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the synchronization collection with the modified data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Contains the sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void _UpdateSynchronizationCollection( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        // Check if the action that caused the event is an Add event.
        if ( e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add )
        {
            // Invoke the following code on the UI thread.
            Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( delegate()
            {
                // Iterate through the ActorViewModel instances that have been added to the collection.
                foreach( ActorViewModel hActorViewModel in e.NewItems )
                {
                    // Initialize a new _hInstance of the ActorView class.
                    ActorView hActorView = new ActorView( hActorViewModel );

                    // Initialize a new _hInstance of the Viewbox class.
                    Viewbox hViewBox = new Viewbox { StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both, Stretch = Stretch.Uniform };

                    // Add the _hInstance of the ActorView to the synchronized collection.
                    _hSynchronizationCollection.Add( hActorViewModel, new KeyValuePair<Viewbox, ActorView>( hViewBox, hActorView ));

                    // Set the child of the Viewbox to the ActorView.
                    hViewBox.Child = hActorView;

                    // Add the _hInstance of the ActorView to the canvas.
                    CanvasDisplay.Children.Add( hViewBox );
                }
            }));
        }
        // Check if the action that caused the event is a Remove event.
        else if ( e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove )
        {
            // Invoke the following code on the UI thread.
            Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( delegate()
            {
                // Iterate through the ActorViewModel instances that have been removed to the collection.
                foreach( ActorViewModel hActorViewModel in e.OldItems )
                {
                    // Check if the ActorViewModel _hInstance is contained in the synchronization collection.
                    if ( _hSynchronizationCollection.ContainsKey( hActorViewModel ))
                    {
                        // Remove the ActorView from the canvas.
                        CanvasDisplay.Children.Remove( _hSynchronizationCollection[hActorViewModel].Key );

                        // Remove the ActorViewModel from the collection.
                        _hSynchronizationCollection.Remove( hActorViewModel );
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the synchronization collection layout with the modified data.
    /// </summary>
    private void _UpdateSynchronizationCollectionLayout()
    {
        // Invoke the following code on the UI thread.
        Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( delegate()
        {
            // Iterate through each ActorViewModel in the synchronization collection.
            foreach( KeyValuePair<ActorViewModel, KeyValuePair<Viewbox, ActorView>> hDictionaryKeyValuePair in _hSynchronizationCollection )
            {
                // Retrieve the ActorViewModel.
                ActorViewModel hActorViewModel = hDictionaryKeyValuePair.Key;

                // Retrieve the KeyValuePair for this ActorViewModel.
                KeyValuePair<Viewbox, ActorView> hKeyValuePair = hDictionaryKeyValuePair.Value;

                // Sets the height of the ViewBox in which the ActorView is displayed.
                hKeyValuePair.Key.Height = hKeyValuePair.Value.ActualHeight * hActorViewModel.LayoutScale;

                // Sets the width of the ViewBox in which the ActorView is displayed.
                hKeyValuePair.Key.Width = hKeyValuePair.Value.ActualWidth * hActorViewModel.LayoutScale;

                // Set the opacity factor of the ActorView.
                hKeyValuePair.Value.Opacity = hActorViewModel.LayoutOpacity;

                // Sets the hValue of the Left attached property for the given dependency object.
                Canvas.SetLeft( hKeyValuePair.Key, hActorViewModel.LayoutLeft - ( hActorViewModel.LayoutAlignment == MainAlignment.Center ? hKeyValuePair.Key.ActualWidth / 2 : ( hActorViewModel.LayoutAlignment == MainAlignment.Right ? hKeyValuePair.Key.ActualWidth : 0 )));

                // Sets the hValue of the Top attached property for the given dependency object.
                Canvas.SetTop( hKeyValuePair.Key, hActorViewModel.LayoutTop );

                // Sets the hValue of the ZIndex attached property for the given dependency object.
                Canvas.SetZIndex( hKeyValuePair.Key, hActorViewModel.LayoutLayerIndex );
            }
        }));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new _hInstance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hMainViewModel">Contains the object that is used as data context in MainView.</param>
    internal MainView( MainViewModel hMainViewModel )
    {
        // Add a subscriber that occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.
        hMainViewModel.ActorViewModel.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( _UpdateSynchronizationCollection );

        // Initialize the component.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the subscriber that occurs when the layout changes.
        hMainViewModel.LayoutChanged += new Action( _UpdateSynchronizationCollectionLayout );
    }
```

Comment: +1 for excellently worded Q :)
You shouldn't get stuttering at 60FPS. The human eye is only capable of detecting 25FPS (or less). Can you post some code snippets as there may be more than meets the eye here (no pun intended ;P)

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson Thank you for your kind comment :) Updated the question with the 'Rendering' section, as per request. I hope this will enhance the current situation and problem.

Comment: No problem Roel, that's what this is about, knowledge sharing. There are a few less kind characters on here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

By default your application code runs on the UI thread, in other words if you write a loop that updated the location of all of your objects via their canvas coordinates, the UI will not re-render until your loop exits. You need to make your calculations 'atomic' sending updates to the UI thread, then update all of the objects in one go.

You mention that:

> Positioning is performed using Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop. This
>   code is running inside an event handler on the dedicated thread, and
>   thus does not affect performance.

I presume this is wrapped in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to marshal it onto the UI thread?

Comment: Updated the question with the 'Rendering' section based on another request. As you can see, I am using Invoke to marshal the update to the correct thread, however, it seems that the changes do not directly take effect, and rather, WPF maintains its own rendering speed and timing.

Comment: That is correct, they do not take immediate effect, the rendering is performed by the framework at some point in the future. You can receive notfication when the rendering occurs via the CompositionTarget.Rendering event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx), and you can make changes to your UI in this event handler.

Comment: I've written some code to track the time (in ticks) from the dedicated thread dispatch, to the actual rendering (using this event), and have concluded that the average delay is 4~5 milliseconds. This is a 50% reduction in performance, so rendering would occur at ~50-55 frames per seconds. This explains stuttering. Is there no way I can influence this?